# jquery countdown - autosubmit form upon expiration?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using jquery_countdown (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to set a 60-minute timer.  I know that I can run a callback function on time expiration, but is there a way to automatically submit the form?

I tried the following, but it failed to submit (although, there were no errors in the firebug console):

```
<div class="countdown"></div>
<form id="formsamp" action="#">
<textarea name="bft"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="op" value="Submit" />
</form>

jquery_countdown_add
(
    ".countdown", 
    array
    (
        "until" => 10, 
        "onExpiry" => "finished"
    )
);

function finished() { 
  $('#formsamp').submit(function(){return true;}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#formsamp').submit();
```

or

```
$('input[type=submit][name=op]').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"onExpiry" => function(){ return finished() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, jQuery is confusing your code as tying a function to the `submit` event.

Instead, to trigger that event on an element try using the more explicit `.trigger()`, like so:

```
function finished() { 
  $('#formsamp').trigger('submit');
});
```