# Submit form when timer countdown is expire

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, countdowntimer

I used [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to make a timer count down for my page. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function timeup() {
    $("examination_form").submit();
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var duration = <%= @remaining_minutes %>
    $('#countDownTimer').countdown({until: '+' + duration  + 'm', 
                    format: 'MS', 
                    description: "Time Remaining",
                    onExpiry: timeup
                      });

  $("#countDownTimer").jScroll({top: 100});

  $("#examination_form").submit(function() {
    var errors = []
    $(".content_question").each(function() {
      var answerCont = $(this).next();
      var inputs = $(answerCont).find('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]');

      if(inputs.length > 0)
      {
        var groupChecked = false;

        $(inputs).each(function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked'))
          {
            groupChecked = true;
          }
        });

        if(!groupChecked)
        {
          errors.push($(this).text().trim());
        }
      }
    });

    if(errors.length > 0)
    {
      var errorMessage = "You missed " + errors.length + " questions: \n\n";

      for(var i=0; i<errors.length; i++)
      {
        errorMessage += errors[i] + "\n";
      }
      alert(errorMessage);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The code from `$("#examination_form").submit(function() {` to end is used to check if user missed check answers for some questions, they will be alerted when they press submit.

I used callback event `onExpiry` to submit form when time out, but it did not do anything. I think it has something wrong but I didn't know where. Before I tried:

```
onExpiry: function(){
  $("examination_form").trigger('click');
}
```

but it just like I press button submit, while I want the form is submited. I tried answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079306/jquery-countdown-autosubmit-form-upon-expiration) but it didn't worked too.

Anyone can help?

Comment: In function `timeup`, `$("examination_form").submit();` , is it a typo? Shouldn't it be `$("#examination_form").submit();` ?

Comment: @dimuch yeah, I typed it wrong :(, thanks. Form is submitted now. But in the case some questions had answers not checked, it still displayed alert, can I ignore that alert?

Comment: Would you like to skip validation and force form submitting? Just unbind the submit event: `$("#examination_form").unbind().submit();`

Comment: @dimuch yes, I want when time out, the form is submitted, but it should not check if any question were not answered yet. It means I don't want code from `$("#examination_form").submit(function() {...` to end, was run when time out. I will try it and post result now.

Comment: @dimuch I think it worked now. Please post your comments as answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your help :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip form validation and force submitting, `unbind` the `submit` handler:

```
function timeup() {
    $("#examination_form").unbind().submit();
}
```